# Correct way to compare ranking data

Tags: ranking

First, I have as original data

```
Rank Content
 1     A
 2     B
 3     C
 4     D
 5     E
```

Then I use my algorithm to prioritize and filter the data:

```
Rank Content
 1     D
 2     E
 3     A
 4     C
```

And the gold set data is

```
D E
```

I would like the metric to evaluate that my algorithm is effective because the data that match the gold set is in the higher rank than the original data.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you actually mean 'results' by 'data' or are the algorithms producing the data out of nowhere (if so, how)? Are the ranks a ground truth? And does 'correct' mean that an algorithm correctly predicted the rank (and you are omitting one column)?

Comment: Thank you @mmh I've already updated my question. I'm new to this field, so please let me know If my question is not clear.

Comment: Friedman test is generally used for rankings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test

Answer (score 1):

Look at "discounted cumulative gain" http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain

It's a standard metric for ranking quality. In practice the normalized (NDCG) is more commonly used.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I have a few question.

It seems DCG use the graded relevance of the result at each position as an input. But my results use binary relevance (Y and N). Is it still suit for DCG ? Also, could you please compare DCG and average precision ?

Comment: From your question it sounds like you know the true rank not a binary decision...if not how can you tell if something was ranked correctly? NDGC is weighted from top down while APE is not. APE will place more emphasis on less important results

Comment: It was my bad. I've changed the way to explain this problem. please look at the question.